# Enabling GPS when no other location service is enabled

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have a issue with getting location if everything on the phone is turned off, that way I should display that user should enable GPS, but the thing is where should I call displaying of the dialog?

Here is the code I have:

```
Criteria c = new Criteria();

            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(c, false));

            Log.v("--", "provider " + locationManager.getBestProvider(c, false));
            if (location == null) { 
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1000, mLocationListener);

            }
```

The thing is that sometime `if(location == null)` is true and `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates` doesnt execute. How can I check will it execute or not? My guess is that i should display the enable GPS dialog here? Can someone give me a guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally check whether location service is enabled or not, when user clicks on myLocation button on the map:

```
googleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {

                    LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                    boolean enabledGPS = service
                            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    boolean enabledWiFi = service
                            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if (!enabledGPS) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else if (!enabledWiFi) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Network signal not found",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

When you call requestLocationUpdates(...), create as well a timer that would expire a bit after the location update so that you can check if location update has been called or not:

```
private static boolean hasUpdateHappened = false;
...

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1000, mLocationListener);
// mLocationListener should set hasUpdateHappened to true
...
myView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
    public void run() {
        if (!hasUpdateHappened){
            //TODO Show dialog
        }
    }
}, 2000);
```